# Splitting string in dataset Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am absolutely new in Spark 
I have a  txt dataset with cathegorical attributes, looking like this:

```
10000,5,0,1,0,0,5,3,2,2,1,0,1,0,4,3,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,10,0,1,0,1,0,1,4,2,2,3,0,2,0,2,1,4,3,0,0,0,3,1,0,3,22,0,3,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,5,0,2,1,1,0,11,1,0
10001,6,1,1,0,0,7,5,2,2,0,0,3,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,4,0,2,0,0,0,1,4,1,2,2,0,2,0,2,2,4,2,1,0,0,1,1,0,2,10,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,2,1,1,0,5,1,0
10002,3,1,2,0,0,7,4,2,2,0,0,1,0,4,4,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,4,0,10,4,1,2,4,0,2,0,2,1,4,2,2,0,0,0,1,0,2,10,0,6,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,2,1,1,0,10,1,0
10003,4,1,2,0,0,1,3,2,2,0,0,3,0,3,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,0,2,0,2,0,1,4,1,2,2,0,2,0,2,1,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,10,0,4,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,10,1,0
10004,7,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,4,1,2,0,0,2,0,2,1,4,0,1,0,0,0,6,0,2,22,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,3,0,0,0,2,2,0,5,6,0
10005,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,4,0,2,0,121,0,0,1,0,10,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0
10006,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,2,0,121,0,0,1,0,10,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0
10007,4,1,2,0,0,6,0,2,2,0,0,4,0,5,5,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,2,0,0,0,11,4,1,2,3,0,2,0,2,1,2,3,1,0,0,0,1,0,3,10,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,0,11,1,0
10008,6,1,1,0,0,1,0,2,2,0,0,7,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,2,2,0,0,0,4,1,2,6,0,2,0,2,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,6,0,2,10,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,3,0,0,1,1,2,0,10,1,0
10009,3,1,12,0,0,1,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,2,2,4,0,0,2,1,2,6,0,2,0,2,1,0,2,2,0,0,0,3,0,2,10,0,6,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,2,0,8,1,1
10010,5,11,1,0,0,1,3,2,2,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,2,0,0,0,1,4,1,2,1,0,2,0,2,1,0,4,0,0,0,1,1,0,4,21,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,2,1,1,0,11,1,0
10011,4,0,1,0,0,1,5,2,2,0,0,3,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,2,0,0,0,1,4,1,2,1,0,2,0,2,1,3,2,1,0,0,1,1,0,2,10,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,2,1,1,0,10,1,0
10012,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,112,0,0,1,0,10,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0
10013,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,4,0,2,0,121,0,0,1,0,10,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0
10014,3,11,1,0,0,6,4,2,2,0,0,1,0,2,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,2,0,3,0,1,4,2,2,5,0,2,0,1,2,4,2,10,0,0,1,1,0,2,10,0,5,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,1,1,1,0,7,1,0
10015,4,3,1,0,0,1,3,2,2,1,0,0,0,3,5,0,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,4,0,1,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,1,0,4,10,0,1,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,3,0,2,1,1,0,11,1,1
10016,4,11,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,4,0,0,4,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,12,0,0,0,6,0,2,23,0,6,0,1,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0,5,7,0
10017,7,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,4,1,2,0,0,2,0,2,1,4,0,1,0,0,0,6,0,2,10,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,3,0,0,0,2,2,0,6,6,0
```

The task is to get the number of strings, where numeral on 57th position

```
10001,6,1,1,0,0,7,5,2,2,0,0,3,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,4,0,2,0,0,0,1,4,1,2,2,0,2,0,2,2,4,2,1,0,0,1,1,0,2,10,0,1,0,1,0,((1)),0,0,0,1,0,2,1,1,0,5,1,0
```

is 1 . The problem is that strings are the elements of the RDD, so I need to split each string and make an array(x,y) to get the position i need.
I tried to use

```
val censusText = sc.textFile("USCensus1990.data.txt")
val splitRDD = censusText.map(line=>line.split(","))
```

but It didn't help
But I have no idea how to do it.
Can you please help me

Comment: Some tips for asking better questions on SO: don't use screenshots to show sample data, paste the actual data as text so that respondents can easily user it to test their answers. And - the question is unclear, please state _exactly_ what the desired output is for a sample input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
censusText.filter(l => l.split(",")(56) == "1").count
// res5: Long = 12
```

Or you can first `split` the `RDD` then do the `filter` / `count`:

```
val splitRDD = censusText.map(l => l.split(","))
splitRDD.filter(r => r(56) == "1").count
// res7: Long = 12
```